# Can we rename a pandas dataframe without copying the underlying data?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to rename a big dataframe and wanted find a way to not copy the entire data. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: yeah just assign it to a new variable. So if your big dataframe is called `df` then just do `df_alias = df` and you'll have `df_alias` now references the same big dataframe- no copying occurs.

Comment: Can you define "rename"? Rename what? The columns? The index? The variable name?

Comment: Rename the dataframe itself.

Comment: @Maya I know it's been a while, but please, let us know if the answer below is what you needed. If so, please accept it to "close the question". Hope it has helped!

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a "shallow" copy, this way you don't actually make a copy of your dataframe, you just reference it using a different name.

Check this example:

```
old_name_df = pd.DataFrame({"col_A": range(100), "col_B": range(100)})

new_name_df = old_name_df.copy(deep=False)
```

Then if you want you can delete the old name:

```
del(old_name_df)
```

From pandas' documentation we have:

> When deep=False, a new object will be created without copying the calling object’s data or index (only references to the data and index are copied). Any changes to the data of the original will be reflected in the shallow copy (and vice versa).

You can check it out here: [pandas.DataFrame.copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)